# Click button to set radio button clicked on modal bootstrap based on value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, radio-button

I have "lihat detail" button when user click it will preview a Bootstrap Modal to show detail data.

I want when "Jenis Kelamin" value is "Laki-Laki" then user click "lihat detail" modal show radio button "laki-laki" is selected.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Jenis Kelamin</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" class="minimal" disabled>
        <label for="male"><i class="fa fa-mars"></i> Laki-laki</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" class="minimal" disabled>
        <label for="female"><i class="fa fa-venus"></i> Perempuan</label>     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit Button**

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="lihat_detail_guru" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_detail_guru" data-backdrop="static" data-nik="<?php echo $nik ?>" data-nama="<?php echo $nama ?>" data-gender="<?php echo $jenis_kelamin ?>" data-tempat_lahir="<?php echo $tempat_lahir ?>" data-tanggal_lahir="<?php echo $tanggal_lahir ?>" data-agama="<?php echo $agama ?>" data-alamat="<?php echo $alamat ?>" data-no_telp="<?php echo $no_telp ?>" data-email="<?php echo $email ?>" data-foto_guru="<?php echo $foto_guru ?>">

  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Lihat Detail
</a>
```

**Jquery**

```html
$(document).on("click", "#lihat_detail_guru", function(){
    var nik = $(this).data('nik');
    var nama = $(this).data('nama');
    var gender = $(this).data('gender');
    var tempat_lahir = $(this).data('tempat_lahir');
    var tanggal_lahir = $(this).data('tanggal_lahir');
    var agama = $(this).data('agama');
    var alamat = $(this).data('alamat');
    var no_telp = $(this).data('no_telp');
    var email = $(this).data('email');
    var foto_guru = $(this).data('foto_guru');
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #nik").val(nik);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #nama").val(nama);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #gender").val(gender);

    if (gender == 'laki-laki')
    {
       alert("Test");
    <!-- //    $('#male').attr('checked', 'checked') -->
       $('#male').prop('checked', true)
    }
    else
    {
    <!-- //    $('#female').attr('checked', 'checked') -->
       $('#female').prop('checked', true)
    }


    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #tempat_lahir").val(tempat_lahir);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #tanggal_lahir").val(tanggal_lahir);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #agama").val(agama);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #alamat").val(alamat);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #no_telp").val(no_telp);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #email").val(email);
    $("#modal_lihat_detail_guru #foto_guru").attr("src", "guru_upload/"+foto_guru);

  })
```

Below is the preview when user click on "**lihat detail**"

[image]

it will show as screen below

[image]

when modal is shown, radio button "laki-laki" should be selected, but using `$("#male").prop("checked", true);` doesn't make parse selected to bootstrap modal

What did I miss? Please help to fix this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this

```
$("#male").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already try that code before, unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#male").prop("checked", true);
```

The code above already correct, I found it doesn't work in Bootstrap Modal because `class="minimal"` later I remove the class and the problem fixed.

```
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" class="minimal" disabled>
        <label for="male"><i class="fa fa-mars"></i> Laki-laki</label>
```